# Avoid [?open] for URL with parameters?

Tags: lotus-domino

We have web application (built without xPages). We have really annoying problem for years with our URLs. Domino requires to add ?open for pages with parameters.

domain/page?open&param1=asd&param2=qwe

Is there a way to avoid [?open/?opendocument] in URL with parameters?

In few words, is it possible to get this URL working?
http://www.e-conomic.com/accountingsoftware?parameter=123
We do not want ?open in URL:
http://www.e-conomic.com/accountingsoftware?open&parameter=123

Comment: Are you performing operation using URL Rewriting?

Comment: Why is this a problem? You can also use `!Open`.

Comment: I would say no but can't understand why ?Open is a problem.

Comment: because we are using another service that track our pages, and to track our pages it simply add paramters to URL, and it does not know it is mandatory to use ?open action.
f.x. http://www.bbc.com/news/?param=123 (works without problem), but http://www.e-conomic.com/accountingsoftware?param=123 (does not work because of Domino)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution how to achieve that. However I found that it could be handled by DSAPI and I created new topic about that.

[how to manage url by DSAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114195/rewrite-url-using-dsapi)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is possible, using redirections in the website setting, in the Domino Directory. You may have to do some experimenting there, I don't know which type you'd exactly have to use.

Comment: It is not possible. Redirects do not care about parameters and actions in URL

Comment: Would it be possible to add just one XPage, that redirects to your current URLs? Here's a live example: http://www.the-academy.nl/TA.nsf/Page.xsp/Examen/MICROSOFT-70*158