# Rewrite URL using DSAPI

Tags: lotus-domino

I need to rewrite URL. i.e. when user send request for 'url1' we will do request to 'url2' ('url1' will not be changed in browser, users should not know anything about that). I've looked a bit around and did not find another solution but DSAPI filter. DSAPI can do what I need, however due to low experience I can't complete that task.

Can somebody suggest me what events should I look into? and what exactly should I do..

I was looking on those events: kFilterStartRequest, kFilterRawRequest or kFilterRewriteURL no success yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just complete my solution based of DSAPI, please read here [how to rewrite URL using DSAPI](http://dpastov.blogspot.com/2013/03/rewriting-url-in-domino-using-dsapi.html).