# Notes 9, rewriting URLs

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

How do you rewrite a URL in Notes 9 XPages.

Let's say I have:

```
www.example.com/myapp.nsf/page-name
```

How do I get rid of that .nsf part:

```
www.example.com/page-name
```

I don't want to do lots of manual re-direct because my pages are dynamically formed like wordpress.

I've read this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Web_site_rules/

It does not address the issue.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114195/rewrite-url-using-dsapi

Comment: that topic describes rewriting of URL using DSAPI, I believe substitution (read answer from Per Henrik Lausten) should be more easy solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you use substitution rules like the following, you can get rid of the db.nsf part and call your XPages directly as example.com/xpage1.xsp:

```
Rule (substitution): /db.nsf/* -> /db.nsf/*
Rule (substitution): /* -> /db.nsf/*
```

However, you have to "manually" generate your URLs without the db.nsf part in e.g. menus because the XPages runtime will include the db.nsf part in the URLs if you use for instance the openPage simple action.

Comment: Doh, hangon... It's not a big problem if there isn't, but is there a way of actually getting what I wanted entirely dynamic? The application is just far too big to do any manual stuff. I am looking for something like the htaccess file in APACHE or the url routing in .NET mvc. Cheers for your help by the way.

Answer (score 2):

To completely control what is going in and out put your Domino behind an Apache HTTP and use mod_rewrite. On Domino 9.0 Windows you can use mod_domino

Comment: Never tried it but is it possible to use mod_rewrite in the IHS?

Comment: darn, that's going to take a while to figure out. bear with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually it is just like an .htaccess file. Get some inspirations here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-92P7K9 not exactly your case but explains most you need for the rewrite

Comment: @SvenHasselbach yes, you can use mod_rewrite with IHS

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a mix of subsitutions, "URL-pattern" and paritial refresh.

I had the same problem, my customers wants clean URLs for SEO.

My URLs now looks like these:

www.myserver.de/products/financesoftware/anyproduct

First i used one subsitution to cover the folder, database and xpage part of the URL.
My substitution: "/products" -> "/web/techdemo.nsf/product.xsp"

Problem with these is, any update on this site (with in redirect mode) and the user gets back the "dirty" URL.
I solved this with the use of paritial refreshes only.

Last but not least, i uses my own slash pattern at the end of the xpage call (.xsp)
In my case thats the "/financesoftware/anyproduct/" part.
I used `facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo()` to resolve that URL part.

Currently i used good old RegExp to get the slash separated parameters back out of the url, but i am investigating a REST solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this, but just saw the option yesterday while looking for something else.  In your Xpage, go to All Properties, and look at 'navigationRules' and 'pageBaseUrl'.  I think you will find what you are looking for there.

Comment: Upon further research, I don't think these two options are going to do what you are hoping to do.  There are a lot of smart people on here, I am sure you will get a better answer.